# Regex: How to regex the following expression

Tags: regex

I have a text message and I want to parse the special characters in it. I have the list of special characters. I wrote the following regex but this shows compile time error. Looks like there is something with escape characters, but i'm not able to figure out.

This is the character list, i want to replace, without the quotes `"<3","<\/3",";p","C:","c:",":D",":-D",":/",":-/",":o",":-o",":p",":-p",":P",":-‌​P",":b",":-b",";-p",";b",";-b",";P",";-P","D:",":->",":>",":)",":-)","(:",";)",";‌​-)",":sj:","):",":(",":-(",":'(","=)","=-)",">:(",">:-(","8)",":\\\\",":-\\\\",":*",":-‌​*",":|",":-|"`

```
return msg.replace(/(<3|<\/3|;p|C:|c:|:D|:-D|:/|:-/|:o|:-o|:p|:-p|:P|:-P|:b|:-b|;-p|;b|;-b|;P|;-P|D:|:->|:>|:)|:-)|(:|;)|;-)|:sj:|):|:(|:-(|:'(|=)|=-)|>:(|>:-(|8)|:\\\\|:-\\\\|:*|:-*|:||:-|)/g, function myFunction(x){
  console.log(x);
  return x;
}
```

Unexpected token (105:52)
[image: Unexpected token (105:52)]

Comment: is it the complete example code ? if not do share, and also paste the error / exception traceback

Comment: No sense in fighting with escaping if you can do it more simply.  Keep your special strings in an array, and build the regex dynamically using the `escapeRegExp` function found in [Escape string for use in Javascript regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6969486/6263819).  You can easily map each special string with the `escapeRegExp` and then join all of the escaped strings with `.join("|")` to get a properly constructed regexp.  It'll keep your list of strings in an easy to maintain state, in case you want to add more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't escaped special meta characters in your regex like `(, ), /` etc.

You can also shorten your regex substantially using character classes and optional matches.

I've reduced it to:

```
return msg.replace (
   /<\/?3|[cCD()]:|:-?[\/DopPb)>()|]|;-?[pbP)]|:-?\\\\|:sj:|:'\(|=-?\)|>:-?\(|8\)/g,
    function myFunction(x) {
       // ....
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for shortening it for me. Can you please explain how you shortened it for others who might read it.

Comment: Yes that's what I wrote in answer *shorten your regex substantially using character classes and optional matches*

Comment: Hey, shortening it makes weak, It satisfies as soon as i press `:`, but i want it to satisfy only when its `:)` like so. Maybe some edit can do it

Comment: its `:|'. Wait I'll share the list. I knw its confusing

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: Have you tried my updated regex? What's the problem now?

Comment: `<3` aint working. Checking for more

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115283/discussion-between-anubhava-and-iamsaksham).